# I would like to have a triangle in my web and filled it with images

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, background-image

I'm designing a little web page, just for practicing(I'm a begginer), and as the title says, I need to create a triangle with a background image.
I have this model that I created :
[My website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5YBp.jpg)

I'm talking about the triangles on the up-right corner of the "posts"

The only way I know of creating a triagle is with borders in CSS, but that won't help because of the image I need to use.

Maybe you have other idea
Thanks !

Comment: So, you just need some code to make a triangle with a background image?

Comment: Emm, yes, it sounds silly, but I really don't know how to do it.

Comment: There are no triangular elements in HTML. What you can do is use a clip-path in CSS, but browser support is not very good yet, at least if you have to support IE: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path And the fallback will be a rectangle, which might look very ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if you need help getting this in to your own code, here's the example:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/envk4PP.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 12%, 0 86%, 35% 50%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I realized that clip-path doesn't work on Firefox and Edge, do you know another solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I have to do something similar for a website, this is my example. I hope you can use it.

```css
.overheader{
padding: 40px 0;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 0, 20.3% 100%, 0% 100%);
-moz-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 0, 20.3% 100%, 0% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 0, 20.3% 100%, 0% 100%);
  background-image: url('http://www.todofermentacion.cl/assets/img/cerveza.png');
}
.page-header {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-header">
         <div class="overheader">
   </div>
  </div>
```

You have to modify the parameters of polygon to make the triangle anyway you want

Comment: @user7393973 (Both ideas are the same). That seems to work, I'm going to look for more information about "clip-path" and "polygon". Thanks both !

Comment: Sorry, I realized that clip-path doesn't work on Firefox and Edge, do you know another solution ?

Comment: @NicolásVera For firefox use -moz-clip-path but on edge you can only apply it to an html svg element. I edited my answer

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work, it seems that clip-path is not crossbrowser. I manage to do what I want with a hidden triangle (made with borders), that has the same color that the background, but with z-index higher than the image, so the image looks like it has been cut

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```css
.post {
    /* not important */
    margin: 100px;
    width: 10rem;
    height: 5rem;
    border: solid 1px black;
    background: ivory;
    padding: 1rem;

    /* important */
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.post:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    background-image: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/614f3577183f1a9219884f73ec2538fd);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    /* move it half the width*/
    top: -25px;
    right: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
    Here is my post
</div>
```

Comment: I saw this before, but my images cannot be rotated. Anyways is a great idea if you don't mind rotating the images !

Answer (score -1):

```css
:root{
  --imageblockwidth: 105px;
  --imageblockheight: 80px;
/*css variables*/  
}

.imagediv {
  width: var(--imageblockwidth);
  height: var(--imageblockheight);
  background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2fb-g_V-UT4/hqdefault.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.imageoverlapper {
  width: var(--imageblockwidth);
  height: var(--imageblockheight);          
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  /*triangles using borders*/
  border-top: var(--imageblockheight) solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-left: var(--imageblockwidth) solid yellow;
  
  position: relative;
  top : calc(-1*var(--imageblockheight));
}
```

```html
<div class="imagediv"></div>
<div class="imageoverlapper"></div>
```

Just overlap rectangle with background image by triangle